pycharm vs command line pytest
When running my pytest testsuite from PyCharm, I have a successful result for all my tests.
When running command line, I get module import errors.

pytest.ini:
[pytest]
minversion = 7.0
addopts = --cov --cov-report=html:converter_coverage
pythonpath = src/converter
testpaths = 
 tests

sample test
from converter.question_parser import readSingleFile, getAllQuestionsFromFiles

def test_ifTheLanguageIsDutch_andValidTextInputIsGiven_ThenAQuestionIsMade():   
    foundQuestions = readSingleFile("tests/resources/SingleMinimalQuestion_NL.txt", "NL")
    assert len(foundQuestions) == 1
    
    question = foundQuestions[0]
    assert question.longQuestion == "This is the long question?"
    assert question.shortQuestion == "This is the short question?"
    assert question.answer == "This is the answer"
    assert question.category == "This is the category"
    assert question.round == "This is the round"

The error:
_________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_question_parser.py __________________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\peter\Projects\kwismaster\converter\tests\test_question_parser.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:90: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_question_parser.py:1: in <module>
    from converter.question_parser import readSingleFile, getAllQuestionsFromFiles
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'converter'



I've tried with changing about the path in pytest.ini, which did nothing.
If I change the import statement to include src. and pythonpath to be . src src/converter the test will work command line and pycharm, but give import errors, which disables the pycharm clickthrough navigation.
Any solution that works to have pytest command line(for jenkins or github actions or ...) as well as pycharm(for day 2 day development) with clickthrough navigation working is appreciated!

That's probably because Pycharm automatically adds your project files to the PYTHONPATH.
When running pytest from the console, make sure the PYTHONPATH variable is set correctly beforehand.
I usually solve it by using direnv which automatically sets environmental variables for me when accessing certain directories -> https://direnv.net/
Then in the .envrc file I setup my PYTHONPATH. For example for the first converter directory it could be:
export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/src:$(pwd)/tests"

Then running pytest command from this directory should work.

You can explicit add src/ to sys.path in tests/conftest.py by run this command line:
python -c "from pathlib import Path;p=Path('tests/conftest.py');s='import os,sys;d=os.path.dirname;p=d(d(__file__));s=os.path.join(p,\'src\');s in sys.path or sys.path.append(s)';p.exists() or p.write_text(s)"

